# How to call webservice using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

**I would like to know the right way to consume a webservice using ExecutorService in java application, I suppose that the webservice call should be parallel and queues but i don't know how to do it.**

Comment: Use java.net.URL or javax.xml.ws.Service.  (You do know that using bold doesn't make your question more important than other questions, right?)

Comment: Yes, I know, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you have an ExecutorService:

```
final ExecutorService executorService = constructAnAppropriateExecutorService();
```

Do something like this?

```
Future<Result> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<>() {
    @Override
    Result call() {
        return performSynchronousWebServiceCall(...);
    }
});
doSomethingElseForAWhile(...);
Result result = future.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The ExecutorService has nothing to do with webservices. The ExecutorService only schedules tasks and executes them. In your case the task you submit would be consuming a certain webservice but it could be anything like doing some calculation or something. Like suggested in the comments you could use java.net.URL, javax.xml.ws.Service or any other API out there.

Comment: ExecutorService has nothting to do with web services, but one could legitimately want to use a background thread to "consume" the web service (maybe it's slow), and one could legitimately want to use an `ExecutorService` to manage worker threads that perform background tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I am consuming the webservice in the task but i have this exception: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://localhost:8080/aw_cerveceria_nacional/CerveceriaDinadecWS?wsdl. It failed with: 
 Got Connection refused: connect while opening stream from http://localhost:8080/aw_cerveceria_nacional/CerveceriaDinadecWS?wsdl. all this process is inside a synchronized method, but is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely has nothing to do with ExecutorService at all. Looks like Java cannot access the WSDL. Are you able to access the given URL with curl or any web browser? 
Maybe you should consider asking for help in a separate (and more meaningful) question.